# Python: DEAP: programatically handle number of func parameters

Tags: python, numpy, deap

In the evaluate function (for a genetic programming symbolic regression problem with binary input/output), I want to be able to programmatically handle functions that have different numbers of parameters. (I have the rest of the code set up so that everything auto-adjusts depending on how many columns are in the sample data. The input is a numpy.ndarray (matrix)). How would I do this with the code below without making several if statements? (In the code below, func takes 3 inputs and the 4th column is the answer but any other run may have a different number of inputs. I want to handle this automatically.)

```
# EVALUATOR
def evalSymbReg(individual):
    # Transform the tree expression in a callable function
    numOfNodes = len(individual)
    func = toolbox.compile(expr=individual)
    # diff = the number wrong / the total number of questions
    diff = (numpy.sum((func(inputDataTransposed[0], inputDataTransposed[1], inputDataTransposed[2]) - inputDataTransposed[3])**2).astype(numpy.float64) / len(inputDataTransposed[0]))
    return diff,
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
import inspect

def numargs(func):
    args, varargs, keywords, defaults = inspect.getargspec(func)
    return len(args)
```

works for a "plain" function `func` without a `*a` or `**k` argument.

Then, you can call

```
func(*inputDataTransposed[:numargs(func)])
```

and the like -- give `func` just as many arguments as it wants, as long as the values of those arguments can be determined simply, e.g by the slice in this example.